# Почему класс не может быть приватным (C#) ?

Tags: ооп

Почему класс не может быть приватным, или при каких условиях он может быть приватным ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не имеет особого смысла. Классы включаются в сборки, а для сборок есть специальный уровень доступа - **internal**, который указывает, что данный класс может быть доступен только внутри этой сборки.  А сам по себе модификатор **private** относится именно к членам классов. Кстати, помня об этом, можно объявить приватный класс таким образом:

```
class Outer  
{
    private class Inner 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: @DreamChild понял, спасибо ! То есть это получается вложенный класс может быть приватным ?

Comment: да, может. Опять собеседования?)

Comment: @DreamChild, да, снова иду на собес. :) по этому хочу знать максимум обьективных ответов на все возможные вопросы ! Спасибо вам ...

Comment: @Aleksanders почитайте [вот тут][1] список часто встречаемых вопросов на собеседованиях и посмотрите также тесты, возможно, они будут вам полезны

[1]:http://www.quizful.net/interview/csharp

Comment: @DreamChild, большое спасибо добрый человек !!!